# how to change the text number automatically in excel without retype the formula?

Tags: excel, function, formula

[image]

I want to get the reference number in the second worksheet named `2020-11-01`. I try to use `INDIRECT` function and it works well. However, the question is, if I have 1000 rows, then I need to manually change the parameter inside the `INDIRECT` function (change A2 to A3, A4, A5,...,A1001). Seems like this is a text so I'm not allowed to drag down the formula like usual otherwise it will return the same value. Any better way to do this or how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the `A1` is part of a string, so won't update on drag.

To change that, build that part of the string with a formula that does update

Eg

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $C$6 & "'!$A" & ROW($A2))
```